# 3.5" SATA HD 1 TB in simplecom docking station does not appear in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: mount, xubuntu, hard-drive, external-hdd, intel-nuc

I'm trying to access my files from an old hard drive using Ubuntu but I can't manage to find the hard drive anywhere after I plug it in and turn it on.

How can I access the hard drive?

Details:

- Hard Drive I'm trying to access - 1.0TB Western Digital SATA 64MB Cache (WD10EARS), 3.5" (green label on the case). It was purchased in 2010. The old OS was Windows Vista 64-bit which was new in 2010 I think?
- Docking Station I'm using - Simplecom - like this one [Here](http://www.digitalstar.com.au/simplecom-se325-3-5-sata-hdd-ssd-black-usb-3-0-hard-drive-enclosure.html)
- Computer is Intel NUC - Intel Core i5-6260U @ 1.8GHzx4
- Operating system - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit
- Local disk space > 200 GB

Things I've tried include the following:

```
ls / dev | grep sd
ls: cannot access 'dev': No such file or directory

ls / dev
ls: cannot access 'dev': No such file or directory
/:
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib64       mnt   root  snap  tmp  vmlinuz
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt   run   srv   usr
cdrom  home  lib             media       proc  sbin  sys   var
```

Please note any output didn't change between having the HDD plugged in and not plugged in.

I also installed exfat-fuse package but nothing changed.

EDIT

I also tried `dmesg`
It was a big output but here are the last several lines:

```
[ 1950.582847] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 24
[ 1950.582868] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[ 1953.688136] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1953.688174] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1953.688190] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1953.688204] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
[ 1953.688216] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 24
[ 1953.688236] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[ 1953.688335]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 1953.690325] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1982.026272] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1982.026312] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1982.026326] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1982.026340] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
[ 1982.026351] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 24
[ 1985.209197] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1985.209255] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1985.209268] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1985.209280] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
[ 1985.209291] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 24
[ 1985.209316] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[ 2664.426899] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
[ 2664.426917] usb usb2-port4: cannot disable (err = -32)
[ 2664.426935] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 2664.431860] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 2664.674803] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4199.949824] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 4199.971289] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2590
[ 4199.971296] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4199.971301] usb 2-4: Product: Generic USB Device
[ 4199.971305] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: USB to ATA/ATAPI Brid
[ 4199.971308] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 00A12345AFD0
[ 4199.976075] scsi host3: uas
[ 4199.977207] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB3.0                    8105 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4200.005847] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 4200.006056] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[ 4201.033668] ................................not responding...
[ 4232.778053] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4232.778061] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4232.778071] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 4232.778517] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4232.778521] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4232.778529] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 4232.779415] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 4232.779565] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 4232.779577] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4232.781688] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[ 4232.781698] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4232.781712] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 4232.782238] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4232.782246] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4232.782258] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 4232.782768] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4232.782776] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4232.782788] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 4232.784669] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Does this output mean anything?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Do **not** post pictures with terminal output, [edit] your question with the formatted text you want to show.

Comment: First of all, you have problems with spaces ! There has to be a space between command and options, and there has to be no space in the path to disks. Not `ls/dev` or `ls / dev`but `ls /dev`.

Comment: After connecting the disk, try to run `dmesg` in the terminal. If the disk is recognised, one of the last lines will contain the device that the disk has been given.

Comment: The dmesg output shows that your external disk has been given /dev/sdb. But it also tells you that there are hardware errors on that disk .. a google on the sense key values suggest that the disk don't get enough power. Does it get power just from usb, or from an external converter ?

Comment: It gets power from the docking station that the hd sits in. The docking station has a power plug and a USB plug.

Comment: Okay .. that should rule out the power issue. But you still have a hardware error. The disk might be broken. Does it attach on other OSs ?